# Loading an image from outter resources flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, loader, vk

After a week of trying different methods, my last resort is to ask you guys about my problem with ActionScript Loader.

I cannot load an image from the URL using Loader as it works on my another application. I simply don't know where is the difference in the code. I cannot even debug the content of Loader object because simply trying to peek what's in there throws an exception.

My code is:

```
urlLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedBytes);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, passEvent);
urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, passEvent);
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
```

Normal loader:

```
loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, passEvent);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,   passEvent);
loader.load(new URLRequest(url), new LoaderContext(true));
```

Loading related methods:

```
private function onLoadedBytes(e:Event):void
{
    var ba:ByteArray = e.target.data;
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
    loader.loadBytes(ba);
}
private function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    _bitmapData = e.target.content.bitmapData;
    dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
}
```

Any idea how to fix it? The domain I try to load an image from is VK Games (http://vk.com/playfreegames) and the image is app-game related.

I've searched the stack for an answer, but none of the solutions presented solved my case.

Comment: Is this relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096820/loading-external-images-from-another-domain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a security issue. From the docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html

"If the loaded content is an image, its data cannot be accessed by a SWF file outside of the security sandbox, unless the domain of that SWF file was included in a URL policy file at the origin domain of the image."

If you listen to the security events, you'll probably see it giving an error. `Loader` works because you're just accessing the image, so it's fine, however `URLLoader` in `BINARY` mode won't as you're trying to access the pixel data, hence the security error. If you tried to access the pixel data through the `Loader`, you'll probably get the same error.

Either just load it without accessing the `BitmapData` behind (includes applying filters etc), or use a cross domain file

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right, having SWF file on server A and images on server B requires a crossdomain.xml file on server B, in order to allow the swf to load the images.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

--
I would recommend to use a library for loading like LoaderMax or Hydotics/Queloader...

greensock com/loadermax/

github com/hydrotik/QueueLoader/wiki

Comment: yes, right. without permisson from vk.com you cannot load data with flash directly ...